# How to check Startup Security Utility values for MBP with Apple T2 Security

Tags: security, bootable-disk

I am trying to check the values for Apple T2 Security - Startup Security Utility for "Secure Boot" and "Allowed Boot Media" (which allow the Macbook Pro to boot from an external device) without going Mac Recovery. Apple. Link: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208198

Is there a way to get this information from the logs or information system?

Thank you

Edit : Apple link corrected